# TSX Error on Object.fromEntries() on Map from Hook: Type 'Map<String, any>' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<readonly [PropertyKey, any]>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Normally,  I can print/serialize any `Map` in React/TSX using `JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(myMap))`.

This works with no problem from any given component:

```
const [loadingMap, setLoadingMap] = useState(new Map<String,any>());

//..
return (
  <div>
    Map: {JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(loadingMap))}
```

But now I have a hook which defines and exposes this state variable:

```js
const useLoadingMapHook = (urls: Array<string>) => {
  const [loadingMap, loadingMap] = useState(new Map<String,any>());
  
  // Additional functions, func1 / func2
 
  const func1 = (id: string, value: any) => {
    //...
  }

  const func2 = (...keys: string[]) => {
    //...
  }

  return [
    loadingMap, 
    func1,
    func2
  ];
```

The caller of this hook references the hook and tries to print the returned `Map` the same way, but hits an error on `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const [loadingMap, func1, func2] = useLoadingMapHook(['url']);
//...
return (
  <div>
    Map: {JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(loadingMap))}
```

The Typescript error is:

> Argument of type 'Map<String, any> | ((id: string, value: any) =>
> void) | ((...keys: string[]) => boolean)' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [PropertyKey, any]>'.
>
> Type 'Map<String, any>' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<readonly
> [PropertyKey, any]>'.

The other items listed to the right of `|` are some the additional functions returned by the hook. One `func1` takes (`id:string, value:any)` and another `func2` takes `((...keys: string[]) => boolean)'`.

If I remove the additional functions returned by the hook, then `Object.fromEntries()` works.

Comment: Where do you see the error? Also can you create a codesandbox